# Why did Hattori Hanzo hate Bill so much?

Tags: plot-explanation, kill-bill

In **Kill Bill (I think that is what the movie is called)**Hanzo** breaks a 28 year old oath and makes the best in sword he's ever made for someone he doesn't even know just because she wants to kill **Bill**.

**Why?***